# PHP retrieve image from MSSQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, image, encoding

I'm trying to retrieve an image that is stored in a MSSSQL database.

It is stored in this format 0xFFE896....

When I query other tables of the database it works just fine, but when I query the table with the image I got an encoding issue.

Using an SQL Image Viewer the image appears perfectly.

To do the connection I am using the latest SQLSRV_Connection.

The code:

```
$serverName = "192.100.2.2"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test", "UID"=>"tester", "PWD"=>"11111","CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

To Query the table :

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Docs WHERE DocId = 12222";  
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
```

To Get the values :

```
if ( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) )  
{  
   $image = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 3,   
                      SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));  

   header("Content-Type: image/jpg");  
   fpassthru($image);
```

If I echo the image I get an huge "string", filled with ??
The result is an empty `<img>` 10x10.

If I have a hexadecimal string stored in the BD why is this happening?
I can't change the Bd :(

The `mb_check_encoding($image)` Sends an error, "expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given".

Comment: Have you tried change the CharacterSet to Windows-1252/ISO-8859-1? That is to be the default encode set.

Comment: Yes, I have, the following error is given:"The encoding 'ISO-8859-1' is not a supported encoding for the CharacterSet connection option"

Comment: Just take a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296183.aspx. At **PHPTYPE Constants** you can see about three encode type for streams, You've tried on type, take a look about the others two.